# Viewer rotates landscape page using lscape

Tags: landscape, pdflscape, lscape

I am using `lscape` with `pdflatex` to set several pages to landscape mode for printed output. My viewer (`evince`) rotates the landscape page. It is convenient for reading, but is such a document still suitable for printing (in printing house)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing should be fine, because the media box is not changed. Package `pdflscape` (or to some degree `lscape`) only set `/Rotate 90` to the page dictionary, thus the viewer can rotate the page.

Comment: Do you suggest that I should use `pdflscape` **only** to rotate the page in the viewer, but leave all pages untouched?

Comment: @chejnik The physical page dimensions are stored in the `/MediaBox` entry of the page dictionary of a PDF file. Since neither `pdflscape` nor `lscape` do change this entry, I do not expect problems with the printer. Make a test print with the particular printer to be sure.

Comment: Ok, good idea :), I will simply test the printing of landscape pages using `lscape`.

Comment: I have tested print of the file, unfortunately the printer prints the landscape page on portrait page.