# What causes rotation of landscape page while lscape in use?

Tags: landscape, pdflscape, lscape

Pdf viewer rotates landscape while `lscape` in use in this [far-from-minimal example](https://github.com/chejnik/LaTex-ICSS).

Example bellow illustrates how PDF viewer rotates page that is rotated landscape page originally.

[image]

As was pointed out in comments, commenting `pdfpages` package shows no rotation by PDF viewer of the rotated landscape page.

[image]

This [minimal example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147507/8380)  gives expected result: rotated landscape page is not rotated in viewer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{pdflscape} %uncomment this  and comment above line to see the difference
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \kant[1-4]
\end{landscape}
\kant[5-10]
\end{document}
```

This is followup of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267453/8380) with the test result : the printer prints rotated landscape page on portrait page.

What causes undesired behaviour, actually behaviour of `pdflscape`?

**A note:** [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163975/8380) seeks the same information and is unanswered as well.

Comment: `pdfpages` package can do this.

Comment: Yes, `pdfpages` package causes it. How to prevent it from doing this will be probably a topic of another question :).

Comment: if you see the page rotated in the viewer from lscape then it is almost always just rotated _in the view_ by the viewer (usually they have a menu option to turn off auto-rotate) there is nothing can do in lscape as it isn't doing anything, it is just the viewer being "smart" and spotting enough sideways text (which is why the minimal example doesn't rotate" pdflscape adds commands to force the rotated view so there you see it also in the minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In correspondence with Andreas Matthias was pointed out:

> Pdfpages is loading pdflscape.sty internally. And
>   pdflscape rotates all landscape pages.
>
> As a quick workaround, please add the following after loading
>   pdfpages. This disables pdflscape to rotate the pages.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\PLS@Rotate[1]{}
\makeatother
```

Now the behaviour is as expected.

Comment: `pdfpages` package is now updated, everything's fine.